# How Do I Load jqGrid w/o an Ajax Request?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

Every single example of jsGrid usage that I've found/seen shows data being loaded through an Ajax request. I'd like to load the grid based on data that's already available; a separate request is completely unnecessary unless it's a technical requirement.

I'd really like my controller to pull the data required for display in the grid, pass it along to my view and let jqGrid do its thing based on that local data rather than initiating another request. I can't imagine that's not possible, but I haven't found even a single example that doesn't use the `url` configuration to acquire the data in JSON format.

Surely, the data loader isn't this narrow, but can someone point me to an example that isn't ajax-centric?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the version 3.7 jqgrid has full local support including data sorting paging and so on.

So yo can use `data` or `datastr` parameter. The usage of `localReader` can be needed see [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data). Here is simple example:

```
var mydata = [
    { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "10", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "13", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "15", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "16", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "18", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
];
var grid = $("#list");
grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', key: true, width: 70, sorttype: "int" },
        { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
        { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
        { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
        { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "100%",
    caption: "Simple loading of local data"
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jqGrid examples [**here**](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). Expand 'Loading data' and click on 'Array data'.

Comment: +1 because I looked right past the array loader because I was so focused on the formatted options.